# Company Name Variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I'm trying to add a variable in Grafana to filter on company name. It doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't show the data when connecting the filter. On the variable page itself it shows the right names, so that also seems to be okay.

I'm using this code right now, which has worked on all other variables:

```
AND "Companies"."name" = ANY(string_to_array('${Company_Name:csv', ','))
```

I tried using `Cast( "" AS varchar)` as well, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Can anyone help me with this? :)

Comment: Have you tried `AND "Companies"."name" in (${Company_Name:sqlstring})`?

Comment: Also, you can check how query looks after substitution in the Inspect menu of panel.

Comment: @markalex This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the set up of your variable ${Company_Name:csv} is correct. Also, make sure that the format of the data in your database corresponds to what the query expects by verifying that, "name" is the column name in the Companies table,  the company names in the database match the values provided by the variable, and that there are no extra characters or leading or trailing spaces that could cause a mismatch.

Try executing this simple query to see if any results are returned;

```
SELECT * FROM "Companies" WHERE "name" = ANY(string_to_array('${Company_Name:csv}', ','));
```

Hope it helps :)